# Re-Running TestNG tests not working for all the Tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I am using **IRetryAnalyzer** interface to run failed test cases again. It works fine if I have only one Test in my TestNG XML file, however if I have multiple tests in my XML file it works only for the first test.

**Root Cause**: the retryCount for second test is set to 1, I am not sure how to reset it.

**Existing open issue**: 
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1241

**RetryAnalyzer.java**

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 1;

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**AnnotationTransformer.java**

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

     public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
         annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class); //to enable for all the methods.
    }
}
```

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BrowserStack" >

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="uk.co.gaurang.libs.ResultListener" />
        <listener class-name="uk.co.gaurang.libs.AnnotationTransformer" />

    </listeners>

    <test name="IPhone6S">
        <classes>
            <class name="uk.co.gaurang.tests.Demo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="IPhone6SPlus">
        <classes>
            <class name="uk.co.gaurang.tests.Demo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Do you actually have any failed test case in the 2nd test?

Comment: @optimist_creeper yes, all the tests are same with single statement `Assert.AssertTrue(false)` so I know they are gonna fail everytime.

Comment: The issue is not yet fixed which can explain why it is still failing. You should upvote the issue by providing your sample (and, why not, trying to fix the issue and propose a fix).

Comment: Does your ResultListener also implement IAnnotationTransformer? Only the latest one in the xml will be enabled efficiently.